# WPF- Data Matrix - Performance Issues Data Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, xaml, datagrid

I have a dynamic dataset, which will display data something like this:

[image: The dots]

I have around 300 columns and 300 rows, and the client wants to see just a small dot, and the color will be decided on the basis of the value coming in.

I tried to do something like this to start:

XAML:

```
< Grid x:Name="mainGrid" VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard">
    < DataGrid VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" ItemsSource="{Binding IsAsync=True}" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#FFBABEAD" VerticalGridLinesBrush="#FFBABEAD" MaxColumnWidth="7" GridLinesVisibility="All" x:Name="dtGrid" Margin="10,53,10.333,9.667" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"  EnableColumnVirtualization="True" EnableRowVirtualization="True" >
        < DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
            < Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="2"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="AliceBlue"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>

            <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="7"></Setter>
             </Style>


        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    </DataGrid>

    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="363,21,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>

</Grid>
```

And the C# Code:

```
    public DatasetWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dtGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        DataSet dataSet = new IZProject.DataAccessLayer.DsDataService().ProbeTest(1);

       dtGrid.ItemsSource = dataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;
    }
```

I am totally stuck because when I try to render 300x300 that is 90000 cells in datagrid, it is taking about 1 minute. I am trying to directly bind the Dataset to the DataGrid, and I believe it should be the fastest way. Should I take ObservableCollection instead?

Although I have read the threads which have told me more number of columns and rows will be a performance hit for sure, but I am finding it difficult to believe that WPF, at such advanced stage is unable to handle such obvious requirements which come time to time. Any help? Any pointers? Is DataGrid the best choice for such layout? Should I rather try something else?

Comment: Have you considered NOT using a grid? I mean, with all respect, but that is VERY far from the intended usage of a grid - so a more specialized control (which also is a lot easier in content) is actually in my opinion valued. Using a grid here seems to look like trying to fit it into a control for the sake of it. I think your problems stem from using the wrong control to start with.

Comment: What process is taking 1 minute? Is it your process to fetch the rows or setting ItemsSource to the datagrid?

Comment: @TomTom, what would you suggest. I hop too much between technologies so I am not really an expert of WPF. Can you suggest what control you would be using in this case. @ Vishnu, it is taking time in binding and rendering. SQL Dataset takes about 2 seconds to return.

Comment: Write your own. Simple like that. The dataset is definitely NOT made for that.